# ColdFusion, MS Word Document and Greek Characters

Tags: coldfusion, ms-word

I am trying to dynamically build word documents from a database (I am using a CFC for query handling). My efforts were successful, but I can only reproduce docs for the English language. However, my app is uses the Greek language.

When I try to build documents containing Greek characters the output looks like this: `??????????????????`. I have tried many things but nothing is working. The strange thing here is when I am using the same CFC for PDF reproduction, Greek characters output correctly.

**The cfm file:**

```
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline; filename=Save-Print.doc" charset="utf-8">
<cfcontent type="application/msword">

<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
      xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" 
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Print</title>
<!--[if gte mso 9]> 
<xml>
<w:WordDocument>
<w:View>Print</w:View>
<w:Compatibility>
<w:UseAsianBreakRules/>
</w:Compatibility>
<w:Zoom>100</w:Zoom>
<w:DoNotOptimizeForBrowser/>
</w:WordDocument>
</xml>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if supportFields]>
<div style="mso-element:header" id="lala">
<p class=MsoHeader><span style="color:red">
<![endif]-->
<style>
<!--
@page Section1
{
size:8.5in 11.0in;
margin:1.0in 1.25in 1.0in 1.25in;
mso-header-margin:.5in;
mso-footer-margin:.5in; 
mso-paper-source:0;
mso-header:url("http://localhost:8500/BookLedger_Final/resources/cfScripts/Header.html") h1;
mso-footer:url("http://localhost:8500/BookLedger_Final/resources/cfScripts/Header.html") f1;
}
div.Section1 {page:Section1;}
p.MsoHeader {
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-color: #333;
}
p.MsoFooter {
}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>

<cfif not IsDefined("URL.id")>
      <cfelseif not IsDefined("URL.model")>
</cfif>

  <!--- Get print details --->
  <cfinvoke
    component="Print"
    method="myPrint"
    returnvariable="getMember"
    id="#URL.id#" 
    model="#URL.model#">


    <div class=Section1>

      <cfoutput query="getMember">
        <b id="lala">#Title#</b>
        <p style="color:##1c1c1c"><i>#Body#</i></p>
      </cfoutput>      

    </div> 


</body>
</html>
```

**The cfc file:**

```
<cfcomponent>

    <cffunction name="myPrint" access="remote" returntype="query" output="no">

        <cfargument name="id" default="0" required="false" type="numeric">
        <cfargument name="model" default="" required="false" type="any">
        <cfset model = #ARGUMENTS.model#>

        <cfif model EQ "member">

        <cfquery name="getMember" datasource="rental">            
            SELECT CONCAT(rental.members.firstname,' ',rental.members.lastname) AS 'Title',rental.members.biog AS 'Body'
            FROM rental.members
            WHERE rental.members.id = #ARGUMENTS.id#
            AND rental.members.model = "#ARGUMENTS.model#"
        </cfquery>


        <!---<cfset queryToString = serializeJson(getMember)>
        <cfset strippedQuery = REReplace(queryToString,'<[^>]*>','','all')>--->

        <cfreturn getMember>



        <cfelseif model EQ "new_member">

        <cfquery name="getMember" datasource="rental">            
            SELECT CONCAT(rental.new_members.firstname,' ',rental.new_members.lastname) AS 'Title',rental.new_members.biog  AS 'Body' 
            FROM rental.new_members
            WHERE rental.new_members.id = #ARGUMENTS.id#
            AND rental.new_members.model = "#ARGUMENTS.model#"
        </cfquery>

        <cfreturn getMember>


        <cfelseif model EQ "book">

        <cfquery name="getMember" datasource="rental">            
            SELECT rental.books.title AS 'Title',rental.books.description AS 'Body'
            FROM rental.books
            WHERE rental.books.id = #ARGUMENTS.id#
            AND rental.books.model = "#ARGUMENTS.model#"
        </cfquery>

        <cfreturn getMember>


        <cfelseif model EQ "journal">

        <cfquery name="getMember" datasource="rental">            
            SELECT rental.journals.title AS 'Title',rental.journals.description AS 'Body'
            FROM rental.journals
            WHERE rental.journals.id = #ARGUMENTS.id#
            AND rental.journals.model = "#ARGUMENTS.model#"
        </cfquery>

        <cfreturn getMember>


        <cfelseif model EQ "cd">

        <cfquery name="getMember" datasource="rental">            
            SELECT rental.cd.title AS 'Title',rental.cd.description AS 'Body'
            FROM rental.cd
            WHERE rental.cd.id = #ARGUMENTS.id#
            AND rental.cd.model = "#ARGUMENTS.model#"
        </cfquery>

        <cfreturn getMember>

        </cfif>

    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: If you output the values as html, do they display properly? If not a) is the data stored as unicode ie `nvarchar`? b) what are your datasource settings (and db type)?

Comment: Then i tried out the following:[link]http://pastebin.com/M5Q9P0rd With the above code only English characters was outputted. When i comment out the following lines:
[code]
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline; filename=Save-Print.doc" charset="utf-8">
<cfcontent type="application/msword">
[/code]
everything is working fine.
I tried it out also in Railo. The above code is working fine only when i querying 1 row (the Greek characters)! I cannot figure out what is going on.   

Any ideas are welcomed.

Thank you in advance,

Tom, Greece

Comment: How are you storing the characters? What is the column data type, collation and db type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried your pastebin example I too got gibberish. It looks like you dropped the `<meta>` tag specifying utf-8. When I added it back, the characters displayed properly for me in MS Word.

```
<cfprocessingdirective pageencoding="utf-8">
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline; filename=Save-Print.doc" charset="utf-8">
<cfcontent type="application/msword; charset=utf-8">
<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
      xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" 
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Print</title>
...
```

Comment: Thank you very very much. Can you explain why the above is working? I don't want only the solution but an explanation also. By this way i have a chance to learn. Thank you again my friend

Comment: It is a combination of things obviously, but the key difference was adding back the `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` tag to the html. If you omit that, MS Word assumes the default which is `windows-1252` for most.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds very much like a character set issue. Take a read through this article http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html which does a great job of explaining things. In this case though, you've gone to lengths to set everything to utf-8, which would make me thing that what you're getting from the DB isn't in unicode, but in a greek codepage. As an experiment, you could try setting the charset in the cfheader and  tags to ISO-8859-7 or Windows-1253. That may correctly show the content. You could also take out the  and open up the document in IE. There's a View->Encoding menu which lets you change the encoding IE uses to render the document which may show what's actually in use.

By commenting out the  tag I think you're letting the browser decide the content type and it's probably working it out to be one of the greek charsets. You could also try using [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to capture and inspect the response from CF. If the greek characters are truly encoded as utf-8 they'll take up more than 1 byte, whereas if they're in a greek codepage, they'll only take up 1 byte. Using the hex view in the response tab of fiddler ought to show you this pretty quickly.

The other option might to be to use something like Apache POI to generate 'real' word .doc or .docx files. It's a chunk of work, but we use it to good effect where I work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The problem isn't in the database. If you follow the link: [link]http://pastebin.com/M5Q9P0rd you will see that i have placed the data inline. The same problem occurs. When i remove <cfcontent type="application/msword"> (that means that i am not serving content in doc format) everything displayed fine in the browser. But i don't want to display content in browser. I want user to download it as doc.

Comment: I'd still take a look at a raw capture through fiddler or wireshark to be 100% sure of what is being sent. Also, you're generating HTML, then  giving it a .doc extension and using the content-type to force word to open it. I think you're at the mercy of how Word chooses to interpret HTML, which may or may not be sensible. You could try converting each character to it's unicode character entity reference and see if word deals with that correctly