# How to create an MS Word document using ColdFusion which will render Japanese characters?

Tags: coldfusion, ms-word

I am using the `<cfcontent type="application/msword">` tag to create an MS Word document in ColdFusion 10. In this document, I will need to take data from postgres database to put in the document. This data combines English and Japanese characters. When I create the document, the Japanese text displays as junk character like %^&*@&. What do I need to do to get MS Word or MS Excel to render the Japanese characters?

I already installed MS UI Gothic so the PDF renders the Japanese characters. I also tried 
`<cfcontent type="application/vnd.msexcel; charset=utf-8">` and 
`<cfcontent type="application/vnd.msexcel; charset=EUC-JP">` but it doesn't seem to work.
Is there anything I need to add to the code or font I need to install to the server?

Comment: Technically you are generating HTML that MS Word can interpret, (not a true MS Word document). So be sure to use `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`. Otherwise, MS Word uses the default charset. Typically that is *not* utf-8.

Comment: BTW, the `<cfprocessingdirective pageencoding="utf-8">` probably is not needed here. While it should not hurt anything, it is only required the hard coded text within the .cfm file contains utf-8 characters IIRC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using utf-8 for charset and [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856213/coldfusion-ms-word-document-and-greek-characters)?

```
<cfprocessingdirective pageencoding="utf-8">
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline; filename=Save-Print.doc" charset="utf-8">
<cfcontent type="application/msword; charset=utf-8">
<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
      xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" 
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: user3889938 - When posting borrowed code, always be sure to cite the source.

Comment: The words 'meta tag' attribute the souce... and last edit dated an hour before your post? #sigh